# How to get 7 days data from 14 days ago starting from friday mariadb

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Im trying to get data of 7 days starting from Friday of 2 weeks ago. I hope i can explain it. I created a db fiddle. I want to get count of staff columns of 2 weeks ago.

Fiddle ;

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jVE6LCUw88dL2u26jG4cxK/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between and INTERVAL gets you the data

```
SELECT * 
FROM tickets
WHERE `createdAt` 
BETWEEN date(now() + INTERVAL 4 - weekday(now()) DAY) - INTERVAL 14 DAY 
             AND date(now() + INTERVAL 4 - weekday(now()) DAY)- INTERVAL 7 DAY ;
```

example
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jVE6LCUw88dL2u26jG4cxK/6

Comment: But i want it to start from friday. I mean 08th October to 15th of october

Comment: then replace the now with the a solution  like abouve